# Why i get this error on Vercel deploy using Next.js13

Tags: node.js, frontend, vercel

My project runs perfect at localhost but when i try to deploy i get this error:

```
Failed to compile.
app/diploma/page.tsx
Type error: Type '{ params?: { slug?: string | undefined; } | undefined; searchParams?: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined; } | undefined; } | undefined' does not satisfy the constraint 'PageProps'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'PageProps'.
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
BUILD_UTILS_SPAWN_1: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

This is the main part of the code where im gettin the error:

```
async function Diploma({
  params = { slug: undefined },
  searchParams = {},
}: {
  params?: { slug?: string | undefined };
  searchParams?: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined };
} = {}) {
  let id: number | null = searchParams?.id
    ? parseInt(searchParams?.id as string)
    : null;

  const matricula: any = await treatMatriculaData(id!);

  const fecha = new Date(matricula.updatedAt);

  if (!matricula) return { notFound: true };

  return (
//rest of the code...
```

Thank you in advance:)

I tried to do this but didn't work:

```
interface DiplomaProps {
  params?: {
    slug?: string;
  };
  searchParams?: {
    [key: string]: string | string[];
  };
}

const Diploma: React.FC<DiplomaProps> = ({ params = { slug: undefined }, searchParams = {} }) => {
//rest of the code...
```